# How to correlate data and counts from columns to rows in Oracle (19c)?

Tags: oracle, count, pivot, partition

I believe there is probably an easy way to solve these problems with pivots or partitions but I can't seem to find the proper solutions.  I have a round about solution for problem 1 by using a long list of select sum()s and a long solution for problem 2 where I just select the count(*) from table B where id = id from table A multiple times in a (select) blocks but if I have a large number of IDs both of those solution equal very long SQL that gets very tedious and I'm sure there is a better way it is just eluding me.

I would really like solutions that would allow me to include a large set of multiple IDs or supply the solution with a table of IDs to evaluate.

Problem 1:

```
Table: 
------------------
ID   DESC   YEAR
1     A     2021
1     B     2021
1     C     2021
2     A     2021
2     B     2021
2     C     2021
3     A     2019
3     B     2019
```

I would like to have the count of the ID's for each DESC by year.

```
Expected Result:
------------------
Year  CountA  CountB  CountC
2019    1       1       0
2021    2       2       2
```

---

Problem 2:

```
Table A:
------------------
ID  DESC
1    A
2    B
3    C

Table B:
------------------
SET  ID  
10   1   
10   1   
12   1   
13   2   
14   3
```

I would like to see (1) how many of each ID from Table A can be found in each SET in Table B and (2) how many of each ID from Table A can be found in each SET in Table B and not in any other SET of Table B (unique matches).

```
Expected Result 1:
------------------
ID  Count10  Count12  Count13  Count14
1      2        1        0        0
2      0        0        1        0
3      0        0        0        1

Expected Result 2:
------------------
ID  UniqueCount10  UniqueCount12  UniqueCount13  UniqueCount14
1         0              0              0              0
2         0              0              1              0
3         0              0              0              1
```

Thank you for any and all assistance.

Comment: data warehousing guide chapter 19 might be helpful to you: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-analysis-reporting-data-warehouses.html#GUID-20EFBF1E-F79D-4E4A-906C-6E496EECA684

Comment: You have the same major issue in both problems - the way it looks, you may need dynamic SQL for both. Let's take Problem 1, which is simpler. Are the `DESC` values known beforehand? Columns in the output of a query (the number of columns, their data type and their names) must be known when you write the query, not **after** the data is read from disk. But in your case that seems to be what you need: columns depend on the data. Can only be done with dynamic SQL, best left to your reporting software (and not done ad-hoc).

Comment: @mathguy For Problem 1, I do know the DESC values beforehand (there are 3 as in the example).  For Problem 2 I do know SET values that I will be evaluating but there are 25+ so I was hoping there was a more efficient way rather than making statements for each one.

Comment: Then Problem 1 and the first sub-problem (Result 1) of Problem 2 are trivial applications of pivoting. For the second sub-problem in Problem 2, it is not clear why you want the result in that form. It can be done, but what purpose does it serve? It would be much simpler to return the id's from table A, with a second column showing the `set` value if the id appears in that set and in no other, and `null` otherwise. Also trivial to do and doesn't require pivoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three problems can be solved with pivoting (calling Problem 2 "two different problems"), although it is not clear what purpose Result 2 would serve (in the second problem; see my comments to you).

Note that `desc` and `set` are reserved keywords, and `year` is a keyword, so they shouldn't be used as column names. I changed to `descr`, `set_` (with an underscore) and `yr`. Also, I do not use double-quotes for column names in the output; all-caps column names are just fine.

In the second problem it is not clear why you need Table A. Could you have some `id` values that don't appear at all in Table B, but you still want them in the final output? If so, you will need to change my semi-joins to outer joins; left as an exercise, since it's a different (and much more basic) type of question.

In the first problem, you must pivot the result of a subquery, which selects only the relevant columns from the base table. There is no such need for the second problem (unless your tables have other columns that should not be considered - left for you to figure out).

**Problem 1**

**Data**:

```
create table tbl (id, descr, yr) as
  select 1, 'A', 2021 from dual union all
  select 1, 'B', 2021 from dual union all
  select 1, 'C', 2021 from dual union all
  select 2, 'A', 2021 from dual union all
  select 2, 'B', 2021 from dual union all
  select 2, 'C', 2021 from dual union all
  select 3, 'A', 2019 from dual union all
  select 3, 'B', 2019 from dual
;
```

**Query and output**:

```
select *
from   (select descr, yr from tbl)
pivot  (count(*) for descr in ('A' as count_a, 'B' as count_b, 'C' as count_c))
order  by yr
;

  YR COUNT_A COUNT_B COUNT_C
---- ------- ------- -------
2019       1       1       0
2021       2       2       2
```

**Problem 2**

**Data**:

```
create table table_a (id, descr) as
  select 1, 'A' from dual union all
  select 2, 'B' from dual union all
  select 3, 'C' from dual
;

create table table_b (set_, id) as
  select 10, 1 from dual union all   
  select 10, 1 from dual union all   
  select 12, 1 from dual union all
  select 13, 2 from dual union all
  select 14, 3 from dual
;
```

**Part 1 - Query and result**:

```
select *
from   table_b
pivot  (count(*) for set_ in (10 as count_10, 12 as count_12,
                              13 as count_13, 14 as count_14))
where  id in (select id from table_a)        -- is this needed?
order  by id                                 -- if needed
;

ID COUNT_10 COUNT_12 COUNT_13 COUNT_14
-- -------- -------- -------- --------
 1        2        1        0        0
 2        0        0        1        0
 3        0        0        0        1
```

**Part 2 - Query and result**:

```
select *
from   (
         select id, case count(distinct set_) when 1 then max(set_) end as set_
         from   table_b
         where  id in (select id from table_a)        -- is this needed?
         group  by id
       )
pivot  (count(*) for set_ in (10 as unique_ct_10, 12 as unique_ct_12,
                              13 as unique_ct_13, 14 as unique_ct_14))
order  by id          -- if needed
;

ID UNIQUE_CT_10 UNIQUE_CT_12 UNIQUE_CT_13 UNIQUE_CT_14
-- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
 1            0            0            0            0
 2            0            0            1            0
 3            0            0            0            1
```

In this last part of the second problem, you might as well just take the subquery and run it separately - what's the purpose of pivoting its output?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  The purpose of the pivot would be to output all the results for an ID on the same row of a spreadsheet.  Is there any way to create and use a listagg to put it in the in clause so it could be created at runtime?  Could you possibly do that with a with clause before the statement?  I saw someone use temp columns and a &variable but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @DBox - If you run the aggregate subquery by itself (without pivoting), you will see that it has results one row per `id`. It will show `null` if the `id` doesn't appear at all or if it appears in multiple sets, and it will show the exact set in which it appears, if and only if the `id` appears in exactly one set. This gives you exactly the same information (in a much more condensed way) as the pivoted output. Just run the subquery, look at the output and see if it does what you need.

Comment: Actually for "doesn't appear at all" you would need a left join (so that all id's from the first table are included in the output, even if they don't appear at all in the second table). Easy change to make, if needed.

Comment: The second problem is really more of a flag.  The subquery gives the information, the pivot gives it in the format that matches the current reporting avenue.  I am using a listagg to create the pivot in statement for me and copying and pasting it in when running the query for the 25+ cases.